# Dell UltraSharp UHD SHP1430 -- Name the defect?

Tags: hardware-failure, lcd, dell-xps, laptop-display, dell-precision

Purchased a new Precision 7530 from Dell.com, chose 'the' UHD UltraSharp display.  There are two hardware options for the UHD -- SHP1430 and I think the other is SHP1540.

I got a defective SHP1430 and made the D: face IRL as soon as I booted it up.  Dell PremierColor tells me this thing was made in week 40, 2015; HWiNFO says it's a few weeks older (week 38 or 36 or something, also 2015).  The screen's been used in earlier Precision models -- 7510, 7520 -- and Alienware laptops as well (R2? R3?).  Don't know if it's been used in the XPS line; found a post on Reddit that references multiple bad FHDs (SHP1431, week 40 2015).

I know it's defective, but what's the defect (or defects) called?  The sides are so dim it looks like a PSA for glaucoma, but there is something else seriously wrong with it.  I can't look at it without getting a headache.

It's plenty sharp; ran it through a bunch of test images but got no eureka moment.  I'd say it's something like the refresh rate, but the effect isn't even across the screen.  There seems to be a blob at the bottom that's worse than the rest of the screen.  (Discord is particularly unusable.)

IDK if it'll make a difference, but not knowing what to call it is driving me nuts.  Thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you only asking for name of the defect? Photos would be helpful. Anyway, RMA that thing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry for the delay; right now I'm functioning about as well as a goldfish with TBI.  My info has been scattered over 8 devices this year, 3 computers I no longer have, 1 that isn't mine, 1 bricked phone and I need to beat Verizon into submission with the new device.  Got photos but can't get them hosted till tomorrow.  I think the issue is the backlight bleed is so bad it's affecting white and near white colors.